# How to get the dropdown selected menu item text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm able to print the index value of the seleted dropdown menu item, but I need the text to be printed of the selected dropdown menu.

This is my dropdown

```
String dro = ''; int _articleStatusValue = 1;

DropdownButton(
     value: _articleStatusValue,
     items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text('Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
           ),
           value: 1,
         ),
         DropdownMenuItem(
           child: Text('Not Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
            value: 2,
           ),
         ],
         onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                  _articleStatusValue = value;
                  dro = _articleStatusValue.toString();
                  print(dro);
             });
          },
),
```

But if i print, I'm getting the index valueof the selected

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
String dro = ''; int _articleStatusValue = 1;

DropdownButton(
     value: _articleStatusValue,
     items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text('Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
           ),
           value: 'Delivered',
         ),
         DropdownMenuItem(
           child: Text('Not Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
            value: 'Not Delivered',
           ),
         ],
         onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                  _articleStatusValue = value;
                  dro = _articleStatusValue.toString();
                  print(dro);
             });
          },
),
```

if you want to have index try this one:

```
String dro = ''; int _articleStatusValue = 1;

DropdownButton(
     value: _articleStatusValue,
     items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text('Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
           ),
           value: 1,
         ),
         DropdownMenuItem(
           child: Text('Not Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
            value: 2,
           ),
         ],
         onChanged: (value) {
                 if(value == 1){
                    setState(() {
                      articleStatusValue = 'Delivered';
                      dro = _articleStatusValue.toString();
                      print(dro);
                   });
                 } else  if(value == 2){
                   setState(() {
                      articleStatusValue = 'Not Delivered';
                      dro = _articleStatusValue.toString();
                      print(dro);
                   });
                 }
          },
),
```

Comment: I need the index(int part) of the selected item also i just can't print that in the value part

Comment: I edit my answer please check it @NiroopNife

Comment: Yes it do work upon doing some little modifications, Thanks!

Comment: If it work please check it as correct so another one can use it too. thanks @NiroopNife

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mohammad_Asef I got the dropdown successfully as asked but did some corrections to his answer

```
String deliveredStatusText = ''; int _articleStatusValue = 1; 

DropdownButton(
      value: _articleStatusValue,
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text('Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
          value: 1,),
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text('Not Delivered',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),),
          value: 2,),],
      onChanged: (value) {
        if(value == 1){
          setState(() {
            _articleStatusValue = 1;
            deliveredStatusText = 'Delivered';
            print(deliveredStatusText);
          });
        } else  if(value == 2){
             setState(() {
                _articleStatusValue = 2;
                deliveredStatusText = 'Not Delivered';
                print(deliveredStatusText);
              });
           }
       },
),
```